# Replicating foregroundStyle(_:) in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui, swift-protocols, swiftui-environment

In SwiftUI, [foregroundStyle(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/foregroundstyle(_:)) seems to do some @environment magic, but it's also not accessible through any `@Environment(\.insertMagicKeyHere)` key that I can find, so I have been trying to make my own version of it to apply to some custom views.

However, in the view, when I try to apply the custom view, it gives me an error:

```
@Environment(\.elementStyle) var elementStyle

var body: some View {
    CustomShape()
        .foregroundStyle(elementStyle) //Type 'any ShapeStyle' cannot conform to 'ShapeStyle'
}
```

I believe I understand why this is an issue, but I don't know what the magic sauce is to allow my modifier to accept any kind of `ShapeStyle.` I've tried any number of different generics or whatnot, but I just can't figure out for the life of me how to store an object that conforms to `ShapeStyle` for use in filling the shape.

How does Apple do it? Is there some kind of magic I don't understand? For reference, my EnvironmentKey is provided below. I would love to not have to write a different modifier/key for every single kind of ShapeStyle. There has to be a way to do this that I'm not seeing, right?

```
struct ElementStyleKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: any ShapeStyle = .primary
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var elementStyle: any ShapeStyle {
        get { self[ElementStyleKey.self] }
        set { self[ElementStyleKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

struct ElementStyleModifier: ViewModifier {
    var style: any ShapeStyle
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .environment(\.elementStyle, style)
    }
}

extension View {
    public func elementStyle(_ style: any ShapeStyle) -> some View {
        modifier(ElementStyleModifier(style: style))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [`AnyShapeStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/anyshapestyle) type eraser that you can use as the type of the environment value.

```
struct ElementStyleKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: AnyShapeStyle = AnyShapeStyle(.primary)
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var elementStyle: AnyShapeStyle {
        get { self[ElementStyleKey.self] }
        set { self[ElementStyleKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

struct ElementStyleModifier: ViewModifier {
    var style: AnyShapeStyle
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .environment(\.elementStyle, style)
    }
}

extension View {
    public func elementStyle<S: ShapeStyle>(_ style: S) -> some View {
        modifier(ElementStyleModifier(style: AnyShapeStyle(style)))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. AnyShapeStyle was the special sauce. I had a feeling it would be something easy I didn't think of.

Comment: `_ForegroundStyleModifier` does put the style in the environment, but it uses an internal`EnvironmentKey`. You can dump the entire environment by adding a `@Environment(\.self) var env` property to a view and then adding `let _ = print(env)` to the view's `body`.